# Origin of "pay a visit"

Tags: phrases

Where did the phrase *pay a visit* come from?

Sometimes I hear instances of conversations like

> I **paid a visit** to the local cemetery to see my granddad's
>   tombstone/grave

or something like that. Normally, I don't think you'd pay to go through a cemetery, but, oh well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Pay* has long been used in contexts other than monetary, and there is nothing in the word’s etymology to restrict it in such a way. The earliest use in reference to a visit seems to be in Shakespeare’s ‘Winter’s Tale’:

> I thinke, this comming Summer, the King of Sicilia meanes to pay
>   Bohemia the Visitation, which hee iustly owes him.

In the same century we find:

> I went‥to pay hir a visit.

In the UK, at least, *pay a visit* can, in the right context, mean ‘go to the lavatory’ (or bathroom in American English).

Comment: Thank you for that first usage - with that, the derivation of this usage makes sense to me: ["1150–1200; Middle English payen  < Old French paier  < Medieval Latin pācāre  to satisfy, settle (a debt), Latin:  to pacify (by force of arms)."](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pay)  If, as Shakespeare seems to indicate, the original sense of "pay a visit" was "discharge a social obligation", then it all makes sense.  These days, we use the phrase synonymously with "visit", and the connection is non-obvious.

Answer (score 3):

> I **paid** a visit to the cemetery to **pay** respect to the good man
>   that had died, but nobody **paid** attention and I left unnoticed.

As you can see, "pay a visit" is not the only case where the verb is not related to payment or compensation as in the monetary sense. In all three usages above, its meaning is closer to *give* or *offer* instead.